# Creating a HTML table from a CSV and change the information to an image if requierements are met

Tags: javascript, html, csv

I'm working on a small project, I was asked to create a small splash table. In the splash table they want to know if one of the services in a server is online or not(since not everyone has access to the servers). so I was ask to create a html table from a CVS in which I accomplish by using the code below

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  $.get('test3.csv', function(data) {
    var build = '<table>\n';
    var rows = data.split("\n");
    rows.forEach(function getvalues(thisRow) {
      build += "<tr>\n";
      var columns = thisRow.split(",");
      for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
        build += "<td>" + columns[i] + "</td>\n";
      }
      build += "</tr>\n";
    })
    build += "</table>";
    $('#container').append(build);
  });
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

it creates the table and everything is fine with the code. but what I need is to "replace" the X that are alone with an image like a green bubble.

the CVS file is set-up like this:

IP, Server Name, Function1, function2, function3

000000, Test1, X,,,

If anyone could, it would be appreciate.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a function that checks if the column value is "X" and returns the image. Something like `replaceValueX(columns[i])` and then the function just has something like

```
$.get('test3.csv', function(data) {
var build = '<table>\n';
var rows = data.split("\n");
rows.forEach(function getvalues(thisRow) {
  build += "<tr>\n";
  var columns = thisRow.split(",");
  for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
    build += "<td>" + replaceValueX(columns[i]) + "</td>\n";
  }
  build += "</tr>\n";
})
build += "</table>";
$('#container').append(build);
});

function replaceValueX(columnValue) {
    if(columnValue == "X"){
        return "<img src='greenbubble.png'>";
    }else {
        return columnValue;
    }
}
```